# Thread dosen't interrupted

Tags: android, multithreading, handler

I'm work on crate server and android client
but thread doesn't interrupted by android client
My android Client has request for the RoomList from server
and Server receive, Client Accept
and fill in my ListView used the Adapter 
here's problem if Click backButton,
than RoomListAcitivity was close and thread was stop
but thread dosen't stop just alive in my app
first Enter has work on sucessfully
but Press BackButton on and re-Enter this Activity
MyApp just White, No Action
how can i stop this thread?
(and sorry for my English skill...)

i tried .interrupt() method , and handler.removeMessages(0)
but failed thread keep alive

upload this full java code just in case...

```
   ListView roomList;
    RoomAdapter roomAdapter;
    Socketservice ss;
    String msg,rtitle;
    String msgs[];
    String list[];
    Thread listthread,EnterRoomThread,removeV;
    boolean staterun = true;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_room);

        roomList = findViewById(R.id.roomList);
        roomAdapter = new RoomAdapter();

        listthread = new Thread() {
            public void run(){
                        ss.out.println("163|");
                        ss.out.println("100|");
                try {
                    while (staterun == true) {
                            msg = ss.in.readLine();
                            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    msgs = msg.split("\\|");
                                    String protocol = msgs[0];
                                    switch (protocol) {
                                        case "163":
                                            list = msgs[1].split(",");
                                            for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
                                                String list1[] = list[i].split("-");
                                                String listT = list1[0];
                                                int listC = Integer.parseInt(list1[1]);
                                                int listI = Integer.parseInt(list1[2]);
                                                roomAdapter.CreateRoom(listI, listT, listC);
                                            }
                                                roomList.setAdapter(roomAdapter);
                                                msg = "";
                                                msgs = null;
                                                break;
                                        case "200":
                                            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GameWaitingActivity.class);
                                            i.putExtra("tname", rtitle);
                                            staterun = !staterun;
                                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+listthread.isAlive(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            startActivity(i);
                                            finish();
                                            break;
                                        case "201":
                                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "방이 꽉 찼습니다.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            break;
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {

                }
            }
        };
        listthread.start();

        roomList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Room item = (Room) roomList.getItemAtPosition(position);
                rtitle=item.getTitle();
                EnterRoomThread = new Thread() {
                    public void run() {
                        ss.out.println("200|" + rtitle);
                        EnterRoomThread.interrupt();
                    }
                };
                EnterRoomThread.start();
        }


    });

    }

    Handler handler = new Handler();




    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        removeV = new Thread() {
            public void run(){
                ss.out.println("101|");
                removeV.interrupt();
            }
        };
        removeV.start();
        handler.removeMessages(0);
        staterun = false;
        listthread.interrupt();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+listthread.isAlive(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: @N Woo,  check the answer posted below, implement as per your need

Answer (score 0):

Go ahead with this, write this inside run() method

```
    //use this boolean value to keep track.
    boolean shouldRunFlag = true;
    while (shouldRunFlag) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);  

                //Do your work............

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.v(TAG, "Interrupted Exception caught");

                // change the flag, so that while loop can be broken.

                shouldRunFlag = false;
                Log.v(TAG, "run: breaking the loop");
                break;
            }

    }
```

and this is how you interrupt and clean the thread

```
 private void interrupt(Thread currentThread) {
        Log.i(TAG, "interrupt");
        if (currentThread != null) {
            Thread dummyThread = currentThread;
            dummyThread.interrupt();
            currentThread = null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for answer this problem but it doesn't work ,Thread wasn't stop

Comment: catch block catches the interrupted exception, write your login inside try block